# Can't figure out how to directly insert HTML fragments into an HTML document using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, include

I've checked as many questions as I can and the answer I keep getting is to use javascript or jQuery to do it.  So I have my main html file:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- I want to insert a paragraph here -->
        <div id="a"></div>
        <script>$( "#a" ).load( "insertme.html" );</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

insertme.html

```
<p>Inserted into another doc!</p>
```

I found this method [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/), and as far as I can tell I've implemented it the same way.

So what am I doing wrong here?  Why is my code not being inserted?

Comment: can you hit "insertme.html" directly and get a result? Are there any errors in the console when you run the page in a browser?

Comment: You are loading the jQuery UI (a jQuery framework extension), but you need the jQuery framework too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are missing jQuery. Add this line to your `<head></head>`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Do you have a DOM readiness issue?

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#a" ).load( "insertme.html" );
});
```

Also, make sure that insertme.html is in the same folder as your index.html file.

Comment: extra note...ajax only works if page is opened from server not local file